# I'm not able programmatically expand / collapse notifications in Android

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, statusbar

I’m trying to programmatically expand / collapse the notification drawer / status bar to view (and later tap on if possible) push notifications.

I’m using the following code to expand the notification drawer but I’m not having any success with it— it complains that I need to use Context.SOME_SERVICE instead of “statusbar” when invoking system services. Following naming convention I couldn’t find anything that was an equivalent of “status bar” in Context class. I tried to call Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE and Context.WINDOW_SERVICE but neither worked.

Is "statusbar" system service deprecated?

I have the following relevant permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

public void toggleNotificationDrawer() {
    try {
        Object sbservice = getSystemService("statusbar");
        Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
        Method showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expand");
        showsb.invoke(sbservice);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Are these specific packages I need to import?

Comment: It was never a supported service, it was used by Android internally.  Even the permission is marked "Not for third party developers".  You cant really count on anything like that continuing to work across versions or vendors reliably.  Its not functionality they ever meant to export, and they can and will change it at any time without notice.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Is there a workaround. How is everyone else doing it? I know some apps let you access the status bar by just a click of a button.

Comment: No workaround. What you have posted is what everyone else is using- which will break sooner or later.

Comment: Object sbservice = getSystemService("statusbar"); --> are you able to do this? what libs are you importing?